# Reducing Array Initialisers

Tags: lean

I am trying to show the following:

```lean
example (n:Nat): #[n][0] = n := 
by
  sorry
```

Whilst the equivalent is easy to show for lists, I understand that reducing Arrays is problematic in Lean4.  But, I still want to show it.  So, I'm trying various things, such as the following:

```lean
example (n:Nat)(arr: Array Nat)(p:arr=#[n]): #[n][0] = n := 
by
  rw [<-p]
```

Logically, this makes sense to me.  But, a mysterious error is given:

```
tactic 'rewrite' failed, motive is not type correct
```

I haven't seen this before! So, then I try something even more verbose:

```lean
example (n:Nat)(arr: Array Nat)(p:arr.data = [n])(i:Fin arr.size): arr[i] = n := 
by
  have p: arr.data.length = 1 := by simp [*];
  have q: i.val = 0 := (by linarith [i.isLt]);
  unfold Array.get
```

And now its complaining that `failed to unfold 'Array.get'`.  I don't understand how it can fail to unfold?

Overall, my conclusion is that arrays should be avoided.  Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried `rfl`?

Comment: Now I have.  Yes, that worked!  Surprised I forgot that --- thanks.

Comment: Still interested to understand the error messages though.

Comment: Concerning the "motive is not type correct" error, see [here](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/what-does-the-motive-is-not-type-correct-error-mean-in-lean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue you're encountering is the fact that `#[n]` doesn't outright mean `Array.mk [n]`, it is elaborated as `List.toArray`, which is better optimised, but also harder to reason about. Your best bet to solve such examples would be to simply use `rfl`. Arrays are computational, and `#[n][0]` will reduce to `n` with no issue, you can verify it using

```hs
variable (n : Nat)

#reduce #[n][0] --n
```

Make use of definitional equality when you can, it's a powerful tool !